# Kotlin messing with java functions?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Everything was working very well until I update android studio.
I am using java to develop my app but now when I try to compile I get this error:

```
    MainActivity.java:47: error: cannot access Function1
        bottomNav.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                 ^
class file for kotlin.jvm.functions.Function1 not found
```

I don't know what's causing this, but I suspect it was something maybe redefined by the update. How do I remove this kotlin error?

PS: I really don't use kotlin at all in my project so idk why it's showing this error.

Thanks in advance, AFSC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you import a **kotlin** library instead of a java one by mistake? Recognizable by the `ktx` suffix.

Comment: Yes, that was exactly the problem. I updated a library manually and used the kotlin implementation. Thank you very much!